# Trouble locating element in array

Tags: java

my code was suppose get the input from user for rows and columns and have them input the values for the array and then sort through the array to find the largest value and then have it show the location of the highest element, im just not sure where i went wrong.

http://pastebin.ca/3463233

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: 1)  Have you tried to use a debugger on this code?  2) If you want us to help, you need to give us some clues; e.g. why you think something is wrong, any error messages / stacktraces, etcetera.

Comment: `if (a[row][col] < a[row][i])` why not compare to `maxValue`? Your array isn't sorted so the above If might overwrite the true maximum valu.e

Comment: sorry im getting error message "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1"

Comment: You should add the entire stack trace in your answer so we can see line numbers. Also, add example input that triggers the error.

Comment: I'am not too sure how to add stack trace on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occuring when you hit the if-block in location(), and is caused by your counter variable.

`i` begins at 1, rather than the first index of a Java array, 0 - so, when incremented every time the inner loop runs, it goes off the end of the array when it's on the last element.

Remember that java is *zero-indexed*, which means that an array of size *n* has its first element at *0* and its last element at *n-1*. So, if your array has 5 elements, then array[5] will cause an error, since that's really the sixth (and non-existent) element in the array.

However, it still crashes after this change. This is because `i` is never reset in the outer loop. Suppose you're going through a 2x2 array - `i` begins at 0, then gets incremented twice as the first row is traversed. `i` is now 2, but the outer loop runs again! The program tries to access a[1][2], which fails.

You have several other problems outside of that function. At this point, `location()` successfully returns the largest value in the 2D array. You then try to use the `indexOf()` method to find the index of the number in the original array. However, when you create a List from the 2D array, what you're getting is a List of 1D arrays. Trying to find the index of a number in a list of arrays doesn't make sense - and thus, `indexOf()` returns -1.

It's like asking what the index of 5 is in an array of Strings. Totally different datatypes.

(Also, storing an index in a double is bad practice, since it doesn't really make sense to have a non-integer index value)

If you just want to find the location of the largest item in the array, I'd suggest making `location()` return a 1D array with two elements: the row and the column. You can save the values of row and col whenever you find a new largest element, so it should be easy to return them when you're done.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much this helped a lot.

Comment: No problem! Make sure to mark it as the answer if you think everything's resolved (: